# Parsing Json to List of Items with generic field with Gson

Tags: java, json, generics, gson

```
public class OwnCollection<T>{
    private int size;
    private List<ResponseItem<T>> data;
}

public class ResponseItem<T>{
    private String path;
    private String key;
    private T value;
}

public class Query{
    public <T> OwnCollection<T>  getParsedCollection( ... ){
        String json = ...; //some unimportant calls where I get an valid Json to parse
        return Result.<T>parseToGenericCollection(json);
    }
}

public class Result{
    public static <T> OwnCollection<T> parseToGenericCollection(String result){
        Type type = new TypeToken<OwnCollection<T>>() {}.getType();
        //GsonUtil is a class where I get an Instance Gson, nothing more.
        return GsonUtil.getInstance().fromJson(result, type);
    }
}
```

Now how I call it:

```
OwnCollection<Game> gc = new Query().<Game>getParsedCollection( ... );
```

As result I thought, I will get a `OwnCollection` with a `List<ResponseItem>` where one Response Item contains a field of the class `Game`. The Json is perfectly fine and there is no parsing error the only problem now is this error when I try to get one `Game` item and call a method:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to at.da.example.Game
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work this way, because the following code

```
OwnCollection<Game> gc = new Query().<Game>getParsedCollection( ... );
```

actually doesn't pass `Game` inside `getParsedCollection()`. `<Game>` here only tells the compiler that `getParsedCollection()` is supposed to return `OwnCollection<Game>`, but `T` inside `getParsedCollection()` (and `parseToGenericCollection()`) remains erased, therefore `TypeToken` cannot help you to capture its value.

You need to pass `Game.class` as a parameter instead

```
public <T> OwnCollection<T> getParsedCollection(Class<T> elementType) { ... }
...
OwnCollection<Game> gc = new Query().getParsedCollection(Game.class);
```

and then use `TypeToken` to link `OwnCollection`'s `T` with `elementType` as follows:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<OwnCollection<T>>() {}
    .where(new TypeParameter<T>() {}, elementType)
    .getType();
```

Note that this code uses [`TypeToken` from Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html), because `TypeToken` from Gson doesn't support this functionality.

Comment: Didn't though that i will get an answer that fast - i'm going to test it. thanks

Comment: You my friend are awesome! Works perfectly! Everybody who now reads this -> Upvote it!