# Java generic method type argument

Tags: java, android, generics, android-ion

I have a problem with generic method's explicit type arguments. I know I can do this:

```
Foo.<Bar>function();
```

assuming there is a

```
void <T> function() {...}
```

function in Foo class. The exact problem is:

- I would like to download some content (Android with [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion))
- These contents are similar (Article, BlogArticle, ...), all implements a ContentItem interface
- At the moment the downloading looks like this:

news for example

```
private void downloadNews() {
    Ion.with(this)
    .load(URL_NEWS)
    .as(new TypeToken<List<Article>>(){})
    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<List<Article>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception e, List<Article> result) {
            // do something with result
        }
    });
}
```

If I want to download blog articles, I have to change url and Article class only (for BlogArticle).

I tried to make a generic function like this:

```
private <T extends ContentItem> void download(String url) {
    Ion.with(this)
    .load(url)
    .as(new TypeToken<List<T>>(){})
    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<List<T>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception e, List<T> result) {
            // do something with result
        }
    });
}
```

and call that function

```
this.<Article>download(url);
```

It's ok, compile fine. After running I get

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.my.packagename.model.ContentItem

The problem is that it doesn't use the explicit class for mapping Json to pojo.

Can you suggest me a generic solution?

Comment: Which line do you get the error on?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24505314/parsing-json-to-list-of-items-with-generic-field-with-gson

Comment: It points to the first line of the class, so nothing interesting

Comment: @axtavt It was helpful, however the library uses the Gson's TypeToken

Comment: @CsehTamás: You can wrap a `Type` produced by Guava's `TypeToken` into Gson's `TypeToken` using `TypeToken.get()` (if you can use Guava on Android, of course).

Comment: @axtavt Thanks, maybe I'll try that if there isn't another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Years later, but I thought it can be useful for someone. I ended up with a simpler solution. It's just a simple, truncated version but you can get the idea:

```
public static <T> void asList(Context context, String url, Class<T[]> clazz, final FutureCallback<List<T>> callback) {
    Ion.with(context)
        .load(url)
        .as(clazz)
        .setCallback(new FutureCallback<T[]>() {
            @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, T[] result) {
                    callback.onCompleted(e, Arrays.asList(result));
                }
        });
}
```

And use like:

```
asList(context, url, YourObject[].class, new FutureCallback<List<YourObject>>() {...});
```

Comment: Three years later, that's some dedication!

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to implement what you want in a generic fashion using the TypeToken approach. In fact, note that for type tokens to work, you need to create an anonymous inner class. By doing this, you effectively create a new classfile, whose supertype is reified as `List<Article>`. In other words it's like if you had the following declaration:

```
class ArticleToken extends TypeToken<List<Article>> { ... }
```

If you were to write the above declaration yourself, you would observe that the classfile ArticleToken.class keeps track of the generic supertype in the so called `Signature` attribute (see [JVMS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.9)). Hence, this trick allows you to access such generic supertype later on, by calling `Class.getGenericSupertype`. In other words, it's an idiom to fake reified generics.

If you turn your code into a generic method and replace Article with the type-variable T, what happens is that the type-token you create is like this:

```
class GenericToken extends TypeToken<List<T>> { ... }
```

So, the info about T is stored as is in the classfile, and if reflectiopn asks for the generic supertype of the type token, you simply get `TypeToken<List<T>>` back and not `TypeToken<List<Article>>` as you'd expect which then causes the problem you are seeing. What you need to make this work is true reified generics, where binding T to Article at the method call site would affect the runtime behavior of `new TypeToken<List<T>>` - but sadly that's not the case with Java which uses erased generics.

Answer (score 0):

To deserialize to varying classes that implement ContentItem, I think you will need to use a custom GSON instance that has a TypeAdapter.

http://www.javacreed.com/gson-typeadapter-example/

Answer (score -1):

What about using

```
private <T implements ContentItem> void download(String url) {
....
```

Since the classes *implement* the ContentItem interface, they do not *extend* the interface

Comment: It's not valid. You have to write extends even if it's an interface.